# what are the differences between G1 young gc and mixed gc

Tags: jvm, garbage-collection, garbage, g1gc

does the mixed gc always after a young gc?
what is the relationship of Mixed gc and Concurrent Marking Cycle Phases(6 Phases)?
what the G1 do during the young gc?(step by step is the best)
thank you

as before as before as before